# Copy structure without pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I'm trying to create an interface between physical components (Arduinos) and flight simulator in order to control and display simulator events from self-built parts. I have started learning C++ in school, but have never been quite keen on it.
Yet the library I use to communicate with my flight simulator is written in C++ (it's called [SimConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526983.aspx)) and so is the SDK of my payware airplane. Therefore I figured it's probably easier to get back into it than creating wrappers or such for another programming language.

Every time I receive new data from the simulator, I pass it into the function `ProcessNGXData`:

```
PMDG_NGX_Data* previousData;
bool alreadyProcessed = false;

void ProcessNGXData(PMDG_NGX_Data *data)
{
    if (!alreadyProcessed || data->LTS_TaxiSw != previousData->LTS_TaxiSw) {
        if (data->LTS_TaxiSw)
            printf("Taxi Lights: [ON]\n");
        else
            printf("Taxi Lights: [OFF]\n");
    }

    if (!alreadyProcessed) {
        alreadyProcessed = true;
    }
    previousData = data;
}
```

In other programming languages, this would probably work fine, hence I tried to implement it like this. However, C++ pointers are a slight bit more complicated to me.

The condition `data->LTS_TaxiSw != previousData->LTS_TaxiSw` never evaluates to `true`. From my understanding, that is because both `data` and `previousData` are pointers to exactly the same structure and thus can never be different.

With my little knowledge and not much understanding of those pointers, how would I do this? Is there a way to copy the structure, so they can differ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about saving the previous `bool` value of `LTS_TaxiSw`?

Comment: That's also what they did in the SDK example (where they had only tracked two values). However, later on this will track dozens of the struct values and I'd rather not create another variable for  every single one of them.

Comment: I'm confused, so the data that your passing into `ProcessNGXData` is also the `previousData`?

Comment: I see, and how about holding a copy of `PMDG_NGX_Data`? is it too big to copy every `ProcessNGXData`. Cause the framework obviously uses the same pointer over & over.

Comment: You can change `PMDG_NGX_Data* previousData;` to not be a pointer. Then `previousData = *data`; would copy the contents.

Comment: @BinaryJudy No, `ProcessNGXData` is being called from a different function and gets passed the current data.

Comment: @henje I've tried that (I changed it to `PMDG_NGX_Data previousData;`). It resulted in: `Error: expression must have a pointer type` at `previousData->LTS_TaxiSw`

Comment: Structs are accessed with the dot operator `data.field`

Comment: I didn't realize that before, now it's working... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PMDG_NGX_Data` is not too big to copy every `ProcessNGXData` you can try this:

```
PMDG_NGX_Data previousData;
bool alreadyProcessed = false;

void ProcessNGXData(PMDG_NGX_Data *data)
{
    if (!alreadyProcessed || data->LTS_TaxiSw != previousData.LTS_TaxiSw) {
        if (data->LTS_TaxiSw)
            printf("Taxi Lights: [ON]\n");
        else
            printf("Taxi Lights: [OFF]\n");
    }

    if (!alreadyProcessed) {
        alreadyProcessed = true;
    }
    previousData = *data;
}
```

If it is too big, you can create a struct that will hold only the fields you need to compare and will be initialized by `PMDG_NGX_Data` and initialize that struct every `ProcessNGXData`.

Comment: That's it! I didn't realize I had to change the `->` to `.` so I was just confused of the `Error: expression must have a pointer type`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Declare previousData like this:

```
PMDG_NGX_Data previousData;
```

(without the asterisk). Now, when you want to 'save' the structure, do this:

```
previousData = *data;
```

(right hand side has an asterisk). Note that this assumes that PMDG_NGX_Data is copy-able and a fixed size. If it's an interface or an abstract class, then this won't be possible. Perhaps the API gives you a "Clone" or "Copy" method you can call.

Comment: Oh, and instead of "previousData->LTS_TaxiSw" you'll need to do "previousData.LTS_TaxiSw"